# Get return value from a function in thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have written a Python function that uses multithreading.

```
def image(link_ID):
    tid1 = Thread(target=displayImage, args=(link_ID,))
    tid2 = Thread(target=publishIAmFree)
    tid1.start()
    tid2.start()
```

Function `displayImage()` simply puts up the image and the function `publishIAmFree()` publishes data to the broker and returns a `FLAG` value.

How will I get the return value from the publishIAmFree() function, while in the thread?

Comment: One way would be to use a `Queue` or `Pipe` to send data across

Comment: or use `from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool`

Comment: Get the return value *to where*? In `image()`? In `displayImage()`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters get return value to image()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the ThreadPool class

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
threadp = ThreadPool(processes=1)

res = threadp.apply_async(publishIAmFree, ()) # () has the arguments for function

return_val = res.get()
print return_val
```

Comment: tid1 = Thread(target=displayImage, args=(link_ID,))   
will this be the same and be used along with 
res = threadp.apply_async(publishIAmFree, ())